# Use UDF to return a list by using two columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have dataframe of dns(string) and ip-address (string). I would like to use a UDF to apply python function I created that searches for distinct/unique dns and correlates that to the number of ips it matches on. Finally it will output that information out into a list. The end results is the UDF takes a dataframe and returns a list.

```
#creating sample data
from pyspark.sql import Row
l = [('pipe.skype.com','172.25.132.26'),('management.azure.com','172.25.24.57'),('pipe.skype.com','172.11.128.10'),('management.azure.com','172.16.12.22'),('www.google.com','172.26.51.144'),('collector.exceptionless.io','172.22.2.21')]
rdd = sc.parallelize(l)
data = rdd.map(lambda x: Row(dns_host=x[0], src_ipv4=x[1]))
data_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data)

def beaconing_aggreagte(df):
  """Loops through unique hostnames and correlates them to unique src ip. If an individual hostname has less than 5 unique source ip connection, moves to the next step"""
  dns_host = df.select("dns_host").distinct().rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
  HIT_THRESHOLD = 5
  data = []
  for dns in dns_host:
    dns_data =[]
    testing = df.where((f.col("dns_host") == dns)).select("src_ipv4").distinct().rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
    if 0 < len(testing) <= 5: #must have less than 5 unique src ip for significance 
      dns_data.append(dns)
      data.append([testing,dns_data])
      print([testing,dns_data])
  return data
```

I think it is possible that my schema is incorrect

```
#Expected return from function: [[['172.25.24.57','172.16.12.22'],[management.azure.com]],..]
array_schema = StructType([
    StructField('ip', ArrayType(StringType()), nullable=False),
    StructField('hostname', ArrayType(StringType()), nullable=False)
]) 

testing_udf_beaconing_aggreagte = udf(lambda z: beaconing_aggreagte(z), array_schema)
df_testing = testing_df.select('*',testing_udf_beaconing_aggreagte(array('dns_host','src_ipv4')))
df_testing.show()
```

This errors out to:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1248.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 1248.0 (TID 3846823, 10.139.64.23, executor 13): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
```

My end goal is to take a df and return a list in the format [[[list of ips], [dns_host]],...]. I am attempting to use UDF to help parallelize the operations over the cluster instead of using one executor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A group by should be able to achieve that. Use the aggregate to collect all IPs and then count the size of the list.
You can then filter out rows which has size > 5

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import Row
l = [('pipe.skype.com','172.25.132.26'),('management.azure.com','172.25.24.57'),('pipe.skype.com','172.11.128.10'),('management.azure.com','172.16.12.22'),('www.google.com','172.26.51.144'),('collector.exceptionless.io','172.22.2.21')]
rdd = sc.parallelize(l)
data = rdd.map(lambda x: Row(dns_host=x[0], src_ipv4=x[1]))
data_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data)

data_df2 = data_df.groupby("dns_host").agg(F.collect_list("src_ipv4").alias("src_ipv4_list"))\
                  .withColumn("ip_count",F.size("src_ipv4_list"))\
                  .filter(F.col("ip_count") <= 5)\
                  .drop("ip_count")
data_df2.show(20,False)
```

Output:

```
+--------------------------+------------------------------+
|dns_host                  |src_ipv4_list                 |
+--------------------------+------------------------------+
|pipe.skype.com            |[172.25.132.26, 172.11.128.10]|
|collector.exceptionless.io|[172.22.2.21]                 |
|www.google.com            |[172.26.51.144]               |
|management.azure.com      |[172.25.24.57, 172.16.12.22]  |
+--------------------------+------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This way is much much easier than what I was trying to go for. And I love that it will parallelize naturally